# how can I sole resolve error for vue, that does not occurs locally?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

In my app I use Login.vue and Logout.vue components, located in

```
/resources/js/components/auth
```

Locally the app runs fine on localhost.
Now I pushed to app to the remote repository, and the I get the following error after running:

```
npm run production
```

the error is:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                               3:05:45 PM

 error  in ./resources/js/app.js

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/auth/Login.vue' in '/var/www/ijsbrekerz/resources/js'
```

app.js looks like:

```
**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');
import 'bootstrap';

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes.js';
import store from './store';
import vuex from 'vuex';



import { createApp } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

import Master from'./components/layouts/Master.vue';
import ExampleComponent from'./components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import ManageCards from'./components/ManageCards.vue';
import Navibar from'./components/Navibar.vue';

import CreateSpeler from'./components/CreateSpeler.vue';
import CardsSpeler from'./components/CardsSpeler.vue';
import Home from'./components/Home.vue';
import ModalComponent from'./components/ModalComponent.vue';
import Game from'./components/Game.vue';
import GameAdmin from'./components/GameAdmin.vue';
import Login from'./components/auth/Login.vue';
import Logout from'./components/auth/Logout.vue';
import ImageUpload from'./components/ImageUpload.vue';
import Memory from'./components/Memory.vue';


// link naar uilteg opzetten routes..
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: routes.routes, 
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      if (!store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          name: 'login',
        })
      } 
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          name: 'gameadmin',
        })
      } 
    } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.
      if (store.getters.loggedIn) {
        next({
          name: 'cards',
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
  } {
  next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
  })


const app = createApp({
    components: {
       ImageUpload,ExampleComponent,ManageCards,CardsSpeler,Memory,Home, Navibar, CreateSpeler, Game, ModalComponent, CardsSpeler, GameAdmin,Login,Logout// hier alle data en functies waar vue wat mee moet
    }
});
app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.use(vuex);


app.component('ModalComponent', ModalComponent);
app.component('CreateSpeler', CreateSpeler);
app.component('CardsSpeler', CardsSpeler);
app.component('ManageCards', ManageCards);
app.component('Navibar', Navibar);
app.component('Login', Login);
app.component('Logout', Logout);
app.component('Master', Master);
app.component('ImageUpload', ImageUpload);
app.component('Memory', Memory);


app.mount('#app');


 ///window.Vue = require('vue').default;

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

//const app = new Vue({
//    el: '#app',
//});
```

The directory structure of components is:

```
> app/resources/js/components/
  >auth
      >Login.vue
      >Logout.vue
  >layouts
      >Master.vue
  >CreateSpeler.vue
  >ManageCards.vue
  >etc
```

Can anyone understand why this is no problem locally, but on the remote server it generates the error?

I have installed vue@next, laravel-mix@next

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see where is the app.js is located in your directory structure but I am assuming that it is inside the `app/resources/js` directory.

Now if you are having errors at the server only but not in the local, I suggest the below possible solutions.

1. You might be running the project locally on a windows machine. In windows, the path doesn't strictly check. For example, `auth/Login.vue` and `auth/login.vue` will be treated as the same but in the Linux system, they are treated differently. Hence, check if the `Login.vue` is not actually `login.vue`.
2. Try to run production mode in the local machine and check if you get the same error or not. If you get an error there too, you might have a spelling mistake somewhere or the directory structure is wrong.

Comment: Hi Parth, Thanks for your reaction. Smart thinking, I am indeed on a windows machine locally....but unfortunately did it not solve the problem.

The local machine does not generate the error when I run `npm run production` I cannot find any occurrances of misspelling. When I search in VS Code I only find auth/Login.vue.  Nothing for Auth/login.vue or auth/login.vue, Auth/login.vue, etc..

Do you have any other smart suggestions this X-mas :)

Comment: In routes.js I have: `code   {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login,
            name: 'login',
            meta: {
                requiresVisitor: true,
            }
        }, `See no problems there, do I?

Comment: The route seems fine. What is the name of the component inside Login.vue?

Comment: Thnaks for asking.. Inside Login.vue is no specific component Just a template and a script `<script>


export default {
    name: 'login',
    data(){
        return{
            username:'',
            password:'',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        login(){
            this.$store.dispatch('retrieveToken', {
                "username": this.username,
                "password": this.password
            })
            .then(response => {
                this.$router.push({name: 'gameadmin'})
            })
     
        }
        
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: Move Login.vue to the compinents diretcory ( insteda of the subdir /auth/ now it works... Do not understand why...

Comment: Try the below changes.  1) in Login.vue change the name `export default {     name: 'login'` to `export default {     name: 'Login'` if still not work then try second number change 2) in routes.js `{             path: '/login',            component: Login` to `{             path: '/login',             component: auth/Login`  Hope by doing these you don't have to move Login.vue to component directory.